# Realod AJAX Powered Page in Real Time without Starting from the Top Again?

Tags: java, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

Certain websites (think Twitter and LinkedIn) load new content via `AJAX` as you scroll down. Sometimes after scrolling to the end of a long `AJAX` loaded page (where no more items are being loaded) some of the content towards the top (or middle) is updated. Is there a way to reload the entire page without needing to start scrolling from scratch? In other words, without needing to scroll all the way from the top back to the bottom again?

I'm using Firefox with `Selenium WebDriver` (+ `Java`).

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more details about your goal? You're scrolling the page; the scroll cause going back to the page top. The question is, why is that a problem - that's the app behavior.

If you provide more information on why it's not the behavior you're expecting, maybe there is another way of handling your case, other than with the use of WebDriver.

Cheers,
PM

Comment: My point is I need to be able to access any updated content in real time. I don't have a problem scrolling back to top. The problem is that if the content was updated after I reach the bottom I not only need to scroll to top of page again but I need to first reload the entire page and then scroll down to bottom again. If there was a way to say "update everything on this page"  after loading the whole page it would save a lot of time.. Hope this makes sense..

Comment: If the app you're trying to scrape data from (I assume, that your goal is not testing the app) does not have the option 'update everything on this page' it wouldn't be possible with the Selenium. You have to remember, that Selenium is only a way of interacting with the browser programmatically - no more, no less.